# No module named 'face_recognition'

Tags: python, cmake, face-recognition, dlib

I installed cmake, dlib and face_recognition but when I run my project I get this error

Code:

```py
import face_recognition
import cv2
```

Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\face recognition\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import face_recognition
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition'
```

Comment: Try reloading the code editor

Comment: @shrirang-mahajan its not working again

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've istalled dlif and etc under some virtual enviromant but trying to run your code under general one (or vise versa)